# Getting MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated for MPI_Gatherv

Tags: c++, c, mpi, openmpi

I get an MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE for MPI_Gatherv. I am trying to send a string to other processes and then have them send back the result of an operation applied on each piece of the string.
Here is my code:

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int rank, size;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
int *sendcounts;    // array describing how many elements to send to each process
int *displs;        // array describing the displacements where each segment begins

MPI_Status status;
string str;
int len_of_str;

if (rank == 0){

        
getline(cin, str);
        
len_of_str = str.length();

}
MPI_Bcast(&len_of_str , 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

rem = len_of_str % size;
char rec_buf[((len_of_str/size) + 1)]; // buffer where the received data should be stored
sendcounts = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
displs = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

char *str_part= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * ((len_of_str/size) + 1));
char *result=  (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * len);

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sendcounts[i] = len_of_str/size;
        if (rem > 0) {
            sendcounts[i]++;
            rem--;
        }

        displs[i] = sum;
        sum += sendcounts[i];
    }

MPI_Scatterv(str.c_str(), sendcounts, displs, MPI_CHAR, &rec_buf, ((len_of_str/size) + 1), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

/* operation on each string piece */
str_part[i] = rec_buf[i]; // or any operation on a character


MPI_Gatherv(str_part, ((len_of_str/size) + 1), MPI_CHAR, result, sendcounts, displs, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The sendcounts and displs are calculated correctly and the str_part vector is also correct for each process. I get the following error:

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Gatherv
 *** reported by process [2730229761,0]
 *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
 *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
 *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
 ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[warn] Epoll ADD(4) on fd 33 failed.  Old events were 0; read change was 0 (none); write change was 1 (add): Bad file descriptor
[warn] Epoll ADD(4) on fd 44 failed.  Old events were 0; read change was 0 (none); write change was 1 (add): Bad file descriptor
make: *** [run] Error 15
```

What may be the issue? Thanks

Comment: if I take your words for gospel and `sendcounts` are indeed calculated correctly, then you generally cannot use `len_of_str/size + 1` as the send count on all the ranks. If you are still struggling, please edit your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Why can't i use len_of_str/size + 1? I updated my code. Thanks!

Comment: because (for example) `sendcounts[size-1] != (len_of_str/size + 1)`

Comment: I had to use sendcounts[rank] for the second parameter of MPI_Gatherv. Thank you a lot